# How to restrict panning and zooming of SKCanvasView?

Tags: xamarin, canvas, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have created floor map on `SKCanvasView`. Draw Bitmap image on `SKCanvasview` and added pan gesture and pinch gesture to canvas view. After scrolling image, it's not restricted and moving on canvas. Zoom also not restricted. I am trying to restrict **panning** and **zoom in** and **out** canvas bitmap image but it's not working.

please help on this issue greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance
Here’s the code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using PCLStorage;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using System.Reflection;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using FileDownloadDemo.Extensions;

namespace FileDownloadDemo
{
 
public partial class DownloadingPage : ContentPage
{
    private bool _isFirstTime = true;
    private bool _isMapDrawing = false;

    private double max_zoom_level = 10;
    private double org_img_height = 4481;
    private double org_img_width = 6033;
    private int img_chunk_size = 200;
    private List<ZoomFactors> zoomFactorList;
    int zoom_level = 10;
    double canvas_total_col, canvas_total_row;
    double map_total_col, map_total_row;
    int col_last, row_last;


    //Zoom in out
    private SKMatrix _m = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
    private SKMatrix _startPanM = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
    private SKMatrix _startPinchM = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
    private Point _startPinchAnchor = Point.Zero;
    private float _totalPinchScale = 1f;
    private float _screenScale = App._screenScale;
    private float scrollPosition_X = 0;
    private float rotateAngle = 10;
    bool isBeingpanning;
     double x, y;

   
    bool isRotatingCanvas;
    // Changes
    Point pinchTranslation;
    SKMatrix canvasTranslation;

    int row_start = 0, col_start = 0;
    SKImage finalImage = null;
    SKCanvas canvas;

    SKSurface mainSurface = null;

    double currentScale = 1;
    double startScale = 1;
    double xOffset = 0;
    double yOffset = 0;

    double originalWidth = 6033;
    double originalHeight = 4481;

    double ScreenWidth;
    double ScreenHeight;


    public DownloadingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeComponent();

    
        map_total_col = Math.Round(org_img_width * 0.1 * zoom_level / img_chunk_size);
        map_total_row = Math.Round(org_img_height * 0.1 * zoom_level / img_chunk_size);
    }

void Handle_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
    
        drawMap(e);
    }

    private void drawMap(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {

        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear(SKColors.BlanchedAlmond);
        e.Surface.Canvas.SetMatrix(_m);
        
        double canvas_width = e.Info.Width;
        double canvas_height = e.Info.Height;


        xOffset = _canvasV.TranslationX;
        yOffset = _canvasV.TranslationY;

        currentScale = _canvasV.Scale;


        if (_isMapDrawing) return;
        _isMapDrawing = true;



        SKPaint thickLinePaint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 10,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,

        };

        if (_isFirstTime)
        {
            canvas_total_col = Math.Round(canvas_width / img_chunk_size);
            canvas_total_row = Math.Round(canvas_height / img_chunk_size);
            _isFirstTime = false;
        }

        col_last = (int)Math.Min(col_start + canvas_total_col, zoomFactorList[zoom_level - 1].no_of_cols);
        row_last = (int)Math.Min(row_start + canvas_total_row, zoomFactorList[zoom_level - 1].no_of_rows);


        if (finalImage == null)
            finalImage = combineImage(0, 0, 2 * row_last, 2 * col_last);


       

        using (var paint = new SKPaint())
        {
            SKSize imgSize = new SKSize(finalImage.Width, finalImage.Height);

            canvas.DrawImage(finalImage, new SKPoint(0, 0), paint);
           
        }

        canvas.Save();
        canvas.Restore();
        _isMapDrawing = false;

    }

    private void Handle_PinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs puea)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(puea.Status + " (" + puea.ScaleOrigin.X + "," + puea.ScaleOrigin.Y + ") " + puea.Scale);
        Point canvasAnchor = new Point(puea.ScaleOrigin.X * _canvasV.Width * _screenScale,
                                       puea.ScaleOrigin.Y * _canvasV.Height * _screenScale);
        switch (puea.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                _startPinchM = _m;
                _startPinchAnchor = canvasAnchor;
                _totalPinchScale = 1f;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:

                _totalPinchScale *= (float)puea.Scale;
                Point pinchTranslation = canvasAnchor.Offset(-_startPinchAnchor.X, -_startPinchAnchor.Y);
                
                SKMatrix canvasTranslation = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation((float)pinchTranslation.X, (float)pinchTranslation.Y);
                SKMatrix canvasScaling = SKMatrix.MakeScale(_totalPinchScale, _totalPinchScale, (float)canvasAnchor.X, (float)canvasAnchor.Y);
                
                SKMatrix canvasCombined = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
                SKMatrix.Concat(ref canvasCombined, ref canvasScaling, ref canvasTranslation);
                SKMatrix.Concat(ref _m, ref canvasCombined, ref _startPinchM);
                
                _canvasV.InvalidateSurface();

                break;
            default:
                _startPinchM = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
                _startPinchAnchor = Point.Zero;
                _totalPinchScale = 1f;
                break;
        }
    }


    private void Handle_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs puea)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(puea.StatusType + " (" + puea.TotalX + "," + puea.TotalY + ")");
        switch (puea.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                _startPanM = _m;
                double xTrans = xOffset + puea.TotalX;
                double yTrans = yOffset + puea.TotalY;
                // do not allow verical scorlling unless the image size is bigger than the screen
                _canvasV.TranslateTo(xTrans, yTrans, 0, Easing.Linear);
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                float canvasTotalX = (float)puea.TotalX * _screenScale;
                float canvasTotalY = (float)puea.TotalY * _screenScale;
                
                SKMatrix canvasTranslation = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(canvasTotalX, canvasTotalY);
                SKMatrix.Concat(ref _m, ref canvasTranslation, ref _startPanM);
                
                _canvasV.TranslationX = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(org_img_width - App._screenWidth));
                _canvasV.TranslationY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(org_img_height - App._screenHeight));
        
                
                _canvasV.InvalidateSurface();
                break;
            default:
                _startPanM = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
                break;
        }

       
    }
   
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: The solution here is to ensure that you do not pan/zoom beyond the containing UI element's bounds by refusing to translate beyond the bounds(for pan gestures) and forcing the placement of the image portion destined to be beyond the bounds within the bounds(for pinch gestures).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example